# MySQL ROLL Up question

Tags: mysql

I have a table of Orders from Customers in my database for a retail store (using My SQL) and I am trying to do a `ROLL UP` of all orders for the month of April and for the final row to have a title of 'Grand Total' next to this total sum figure:

```
SELECT coalesce (OrderID, 'GrandTotal') AS OrderID, 
SUM(OrderPrice) as SumOrderPrice
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30'
GROUP BY OrderPrice WITH ROLLUP;
```

The problem I am having is that when I run this code, next to the total 'Sum' figure, I am getting a duplicate OrderID number, not the text 'Grand Total'. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? 
Many thanks

Comment: Can you give an example as DBFiddle or as CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qS515ShyFGxgj4h6Ga6HA3/0#&togetherjs=aNgE8G0yMh

Comment: I agree with Lennart. We need more data **in a suitable format** to properly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Verace. Apologies, hopefully there is sufficient info here:

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qS515ShyFGxgj4h6Ga6HA3/0#&togetherjs=aNgE8G0yMh

Comment: Thanks for the DBFiddle, what is the expected result for the sample you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do, the GROUP BY clause that you provided is invalid. Is the following what you meant?

```
SELECT coalesce (OrderID, 'GrandTotal') AS OrderID, 
       SUM(OrderPrice) as SumOrderPrice
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30'
GROUP BY OrderID WITH ROLLUP;
```

I.e. GROUP BY OrderID instead of OrderPrice?

Comment: Hi Lennart, thank you, yes that's where my error was, the GROUP BY should be by OrderID